# Can cygwin shell interfere with git bash when using Git Bash Here?

Tags: windows-7, git, cygwin, mingw

I've been using Cygwin terminal for a long time, and have gotten very used to its quirks and what-not.

Recently I've been using the Git Bash shell in Windows 7 (64-bit).  For Git command-line work, I prefer it over the DOS CMD box. Cygwin shell seems to find git file changes when it's a file line ending or some other nonsense (but that's not why I'm posting this question).

I'm experiencing something odd -and I'm not sure if it's my environment, the installed programs (Cygwin or Git Bash) or the possibility of cygwin's settings overtaking one a feature of Git Bash.

When I right-click on a folder in Windows Explorer, the context menu has a `Git Bash Here` option. But when I select it, the Git Bash always opens up with its `pwd` in my cygwin home directory.

I've checked my cygwin .bash_profile and .bashrc and I don't see any customized forcing of a specific home directory.

On a different computer with Windows 8, this feature works flawlessly even with Cygwin also installed.

Any ideas as to what to try? Thanks, Adam

Comment: dunno n i've hardly used git, but perhaps you can clarify when you say it shows your home directory,  is that /home or /home/user? and maybe this is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494658/how-can-i-change-my-cygwin-home-folder-after-installation

Comment: @barlop at any point when Git Bash here launches the MINGW32 shell, it is in my home directory as per cygwin. In other words whatever my cygwin home directory is - is the pwd no matter what folder is right-clicked in Windows Explorer and selecting the "Git Bash Here" option. For example, if i right-click folder C:\bob, I would expect Git Bash to open in directory `/c/bob` but instead it opens in my cygwin user home directory.